# In Scrapy redirect, get ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:

Tags: python, url, scrapy, redirect

When I run my Scrapy to Amazon, I got error of missing scheme in the URL on redirect. How can I make sure every redirect URL have `http`?

```
2016-11-17 07:16:22 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.amazon.com/b/ref=lp_3610851_ln_1?node=3752871&ie=UTF8&qid=1479333096> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\Python Projects\<project_name>\<project_name>\<project_name>\<project_name>\spiders\amazon.py", line 133, in parse
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_items, meta=response.meta)
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 57, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: /gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_btf_browse_lawngarden_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00535191JPLEGR67F8IR&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FRock-Solid-Supplement-Flowering-Hydroponic%2Fdp%2FB00YBHBKP2%2Fref%3Dlp_3752871_1_25%2F161-3753912-4487915%3Fs%3Dlawn-garden%26ie%3DUTF8%26qid%3D1479341778%26sr%3D1-25-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1479341778&id=6512557339213691&widgetName=sp_btf_browse
```

**UPDATE**

I review the base redirect middleware in Scrapy and I find out that it already contains this:

```
    location = safe_url_string(response.headers['location'])

    redirected_url = urljoin(request.url, location)
```

So logically it should already fix the redirect URL. Why do I still have broken redirect URL?

**UPDATE**

I already use `urljoin` in my yields.

```
def parse(self, response):
    for url in response.xpath(
        '//div[@id="mainResults"]//a[h2/@data-attribute]/@href'
        ).extract():
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse_items, meta=response.meta)
```

Comment: check if url starts with `http` and add it manually.

Comment: It's clear it has no `http`, but I don't know how to modify the redirect url

Comment: is it `url` which you use in `yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_items, meta=response.meta)` ? So you have access to this `url` and you can check it.

Comment: not that initial url, but the "redirect" url

Comment: I don't see any `redirect` url in error message - only your `url` which you use in `yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_items, meta=response.meta)` in file `<project_name>\<project_name>\amazon.py` in line 133. Print it to see what you have.

Comment: I've updated the error log to be more complete

Comment: Do you have a sample page URL, a page that goes through parse and for which `yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url),...)` generates a URL without `http://`?

Comment: Sample: https://www.amazon.com/b/ref=lp_2972638011_ln_0_12?node=3480662011&ie=UTF8&qid=1478317691

Answer (score 4):

I do not think this has to do with redirects.

This is where you should look into:

```
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\Python Projects\<project_name>\<project_name>\<project_name>\<project_name>\spiders\amazon.py", line 133, in parse
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_items, meta=response.meta)
```

Your `parse` callback is yielding a `scrapy.Request` instance with a `url` that is not complete -- it's missing `http://` or `https://` at the beginning, and `scrapy.Request` initialization complains about it.

[Scrapy `Response` objects have a helper method](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin) called `.urljoin()` to build complete absolute URLs from relative locations like `/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html...`:

```
 response.urljoin(url)
```

So I suggest that you change that part of your code to something like:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse_items, meta=response.meta)
```

Comment: This does not appear in your stacktrace. Can you share more code?

Comment: Updated! Please review

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
for url in urls:    
myRequest = Request("http://www.amazon.com" + url.pop(0), callback=self.whateverfunction)   
yeild myRequest
```